# MVC.net 4 - Partial View : Repost to self with text input

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, partial-views

I am using a partial view to display a chart. I have added some input controls to the partial view  so that the chart can be re-generated.

I have this working partially. However the chart is not being generated in the original Partial view it just opens another view.

**Partial View:**

```
@model DataCatalogV2.Models.DC.ImageModel
<img id="imgWSChart" src="data:image/png;base64,@System.Convert.ToBase64String(Model.image)" alt="Workspace Chart" /> 

@using (Html.BeginForm("QA_ChartRePost","Chart",FormMethod.Post, new { id = "Chart_Request" }))
{
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <button>Reset</button>
            </td>
             <td>
                <label>Start Range:</label>
            </td>
             <td>
                <input id='QAstartRange' value='@DataCatalogV2.Controllers.ChartController.dtSeriesStartDate' style='width: 185px;' />
            </td>
              <td>
                <label>End Range:</label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input id='QAendRange' value='@DataCatalogV2.Controllers.ChartController.dtSeriesEndDate' style='width: 185px;' />
            </td>
            <td>
                <button>Plot Range</button>

            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
}
```

**Controller:**

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
    public ActionResult QA_ChartRePost(String Measurement, String Type, String Name, String Units, String StartDate, String EndDate, String HideQAFail, String Token)
    {
        DataCatalogV2.Models.DC.ImageModel item = new Models.DC.ImageModel();
        dtStartDate = Convert.ToDateTime(StartDate);
        dtEndDate = Convert.ToDateTime(EndDate);


        EyascoDBController EC = new EyascoDBController();
        if (EC.HasAccess(AppName))
        {
            //Dummy Vars
            item.image = MRMChart("1002.500.131.1.1", "500 - USBR - Temperature 1", "Degrees C", "5/30/2002 21:50", "5/13/2013 23:50", "true", "NONE1395870778280");
            //item.image = MRMChart(Measurement, Name, Units, StartDate, EndDate, HideQAFail, Token);
        }
        //return View(item);
        return PartialView("QA_Chart", item);
    }
```

**JS - Original Call to Partial View**

```
function popupChartQA(Measurement, Type, Name, Units, StartDate, EndDate, HideQAFail) {
var url;
Name = encodeURIComponent(Name);
Measurement = encodeURIComponent(Measurement);
var token = "NONE" + new Date().getTime(); //unique Token to force chart re-generation
url = baseUrl + "/Chart/QA_Chart?Measurement=" + Measurement + "&Type=" + Type + "&Name=" + Name + "&Units=" + Units + "&StartDate=" + StartDate + "&EndDate=" + EndDate + "&HideQAFail=" + HideQAFail + "&Token=" + encodeURIComponent(token);
showWaiting("Chart - QA");


$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: url,
    dataType: "html",
    success: function (data) {
        //alert( " Token:" + Token + "data: " + data);
        $("#chartDiv").html(data);
    }            });
```

2 questions:

1. How do I get the chart to be regenerated on the original requesting partial view?
2. How do I pass the new chart parameters back to the controller if my model (image) does not have this attributes exposed (define a dictionary?).

Comment: Up is it the view or the Partial View?

Comment: @lnanikian - That is the partial view.
The I am able to hit the desired action(QA_ChartRePost), and it generates the desired chart but not in the Partial view it re-renders the main view (which I didn't post because it doesn't seem like relevant).
I also am not sure how to assemble the specified dictionary: id = "Chart_Request"?

Not sure that submitting form is correct either.

Comment: As you said that it opens in another view. Can you show me the code of this action? Also you don't pass the correct object to your actions. Then I can try to answer.

Comment: Thanks for your response and request for clarification.
I had wanted to only post the relevant code so as to avoid clutter and confusion.

I added the model reference to the Partial view code.
The action that calls the is in the Form definition.
        @using (Html.BeginForm("QA_ChartRePost", "Chart", FormMethod.Get ,new { id = "Chart_Request" }))
it will get triggred by a form submit which in this case can just be "Enter"

Comment: Hi, Is your partial view nested in the form of your View? To retreive parameters from your image you have two choice either using Javascript . I know there is library to do that but not quite sure noe to send this image to the server and then use code to get parameters. How do you render your partial view in the main view?

Comment: please see added original (jQuery) call to partial view.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this issue Partially by just making the Partial View a (Full) view.

**Now I just need to pass the the model object back to View ???**
(Do I use form submit?)

```
 @using (Html.BeginForm("QA_ChartRePost", "Chart", FormMethod.Get ,new { id = "Chart_Request" }))
```

**New View**

```
@model DataCatalogV2.Models.DC.WSIMG
@{
ViewBag.Title = "ControlChart";
ViewBag.BaseURL = DataCatalogV2.Controllers.HomeController.GetBaseUrl();
}

<script type="text/javascript">
var di = grid.dataItem(grid.select());

$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#QAstartdate").kendoDateTimePicker({
        //value: new Date(2014, 1, 1)
    });
    $("#QAstartRange").kendoDateTimePicker({
        value: new Date(2013, 1, 1)
    });
    $("#QAendRange").kendoDateTimePicker({
        value: new Date()
    });
});
</script>

<h2>ControlChart</h2>

<div id="ChartConrols"/>
<div dir="ltr" style="background-color: tan; display:inline-block; azimuth:left-side; float:left">
 <img id="imgWSChart" src="data:image/png;base64,@System.Convert.ToBase64String(Model.myIM.image)" alt="Workspace Chart" />


<div>
@using (Html.BeginForm("QA_ChartRePost", "Chart", FormMethod.Get ,new { id = "Chart_Request" }))
{
       <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <button>Reset</button>
            </td>
             <td>
                <label>Start Range:</label>
            </td>
             <td>
                <input id='QAstartRange' value='@DataCatalogV2.Controllers.ChartController.dtSeriesStartDate' style='width: 185px;' />
            </td>
              <td>
                <label>End Range:</label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input id='QAendRange' value='@DataCatalogV2.Controllers.ChartController.dtSeriesEndDate' style='width: 185px;' />
            </td>
            <td>
                <button>Plot Range</button>

            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
}

</div>
</div>
```

and by compiling both the models I was needing (image model Working series model into one Model)
 **New Model**

```
    public class WSIMG
{
    public ImageModel myIM { get; set;}
    public WorkingSeries myWS { get; set;}
}

public class WorkingSeries
{
    [Key]
    public Int32 id { get; set; }
    public String Type { get; set; }
    public String Name { get; set; }
    public String Lookup { get; set; }
    public String Units { get; set; }
    public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime EndDate { get; set; }
    public Boolean HideQAFail { get; set; }
    public Boolean MultiChart { get; set; }
}
 public class ImageModel
{
    public byte[] image { get; set; }
}
```

**New Controller action**

```
 [HttpGet]
    //public ActionResult QA_ChartRePost(String Measurement, String Type, String Name, String Units, String StartDate, String EndDate, String HideQAFail, String Token)
    public ActionResult QA_ChartRePost(WSIMG WSIMGmodel)
    {
        //ImageModel item = WSIMGmodel.myIM;

        EyascoDBController EC = new EyascoDBController();
        if (EC.HasAccess(AppName))
        {
        WSIMGmodel.myIM.image = MRMChart(WSIMGmodel.myWS.Lookup, WSIMGmodel.myWS.Name, WSIMGmodel.myWS.Units, WSIMGmodel.myWS.StartDate.ToString(), WSIMGmodel.myWS.EndDate.ToString(), WSIMGmodel.myWS.HideQAFail.ToString(), "NONE1395870778280");
        }
        return PartialView("ControlChart", WSIMGmodel); 

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove the object `new {id ="Chart_Request"}` and instead of `GET` put `FormMethod.Post`.